# Empathy doesn't seem to be saving my display picture

Tags: gnome, display, empathy

Hey how do I force empathy to save my display pic? I have tried to set it (in different formats and sizes) over a dozen times, all I get is this little silver man.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Doesn't Empathy use your userpic from your account on Ubuntu?  If you don't have a userpic set on your computer, you might not have one set for Empathy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think pictures are stored *on the protocol server*, not on your local Empathy client (except maybe as cached data), so you should be able to upload a profile picture from any account/profile management web page.  For instance, I can see in Empathy the picture that I upload from my GMail account.

Comment: I've pinpointed the issue to be telepathy-butterfly (when I use telepathy-haze my avatar is displayed), you wouldn't know if there is a way to "force" telepathy-butterfly to show your avatar in chat would you?